# Can someone tell me how to code a SWITCH statement for the below situation for selection of values within a field?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, return-value

In my report I am trying to display only the values in the role_sk field being 3936, 4310 or 4216 to which the last_name, first_name column populates as well but anything other than the specified values above should return a blank in the role_sk column as well as the last_name, first_name column. I can get the role_sk column to populate with the specified values but if my false statement is "", it enters a blank in the role_sk column as wanted but the last_name, first_name column still populates with other values that do not correspond to the three values above.

Here is the expression I have set in that field right now.

```
   =SWITCH(Fields!role_sk.Value = 3936, "Lead Attorney", Fields!role_sk.Value = 4310, "Bankruptcy Manager", Fields!role_sk.Value = 4216, "Partner in Charge", True,"")
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! that's commendable. but difficult to help with, since we don't know anything about your data or code. a minimal example would help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL, you can do this in your SQL statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MyField IN (3936, 4310, 4216) THEN MyField END AS MyField
FROM MyTable
```

You could also do it in your report using an expression for the cell value:

```
=IIF(Fields!MyField.Value = 3936 OR Fields!MyField.Value = 4310 OR Fields!MyField.Value = 4216, Fields!MyField.Value, Nothing)
```

Comment: I tried adding this IIf statement but I am getting an error. Here is what I entered:                                                =IIf(Fields!role_sk.Value = 3936, "Lead Attorney", IIf(Fields!role_sk.Value = 4310, "Bankruptcy Manager", IIf(Fields!role_sk.Value = 4216, "Partner in Charge", " ", IIf(Fields!role_sk.Value = 3936 OR IIf(Fields!role_sk.Value = 4310 OR IIf(Fields!role_sk.Value = 4216, Fields!role_sk.Value, NOTHING))))))